# Should I add extension=xdebug.so to load xdebug as a php module or not?

Tags: xdebug

First, http://xdebug.org/docs/install says

Note: You should ignore any prompts to add "extension=xdebug.so" to php.ini — this will cause problems.

Second, http://xdebug.org/docs/install says

Xdebug should appear twice there (once under 'PHP Modules' and once under 'Zend Modules').

Answer (score 1):

The docs clearly say:

> you still need to add the correct line
>   to your php.ini: (don't forget to
>   change the path and filename to the
>   correct one — but make sure you use
>   the full path)
>
> zend_extension="/usr/local/php/modules/xdebug.so"
>
> Note: You should ignore any prompts to
>   add "extension=xdebug.so" to php.ini —
>   this will cause problems.

at http://xdebug.org/docs/install

Answer (score 0):

if you add **zend_extension="/usr/local/php/modules/xdebug.so"** line in php.ini
then IGNORE the prompt